# Why can't I track the click event in a document class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Consider the code below: why can't I track the click event ??

```
            package {
                import flash.display.Sprite;
            import flash.events.MouseEvent;
            import flash.display.*;
            [SWF(width="1000",height="600")]
                public class vanCopperTes extends Sprite
                {
                    public function vanCopperTes()
                    {
                        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
                        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

                        //黄色矩形
                        graphics.beginFill(0xFFCC00,.5);
                        graphics.drawRect(0,0,200,200);
                        graphics.endFill();
                        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onClick);
                        trace("this.numChilder",numChildren);// output: 0

                    }

                    private function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
                    {
                        trace("Click");
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: I would guess that it is because you don't have anything "mouse enabled" like sprite if you add a sprite and draw in it you will get the click.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the eventlistener to:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onClick);
```

This will work for the whole .swf.  If you want to have it just the yellow square, you need to add that as a separate sprite and attach the listener to that.